# Will non local constants be initialized before used by lambda executed from another thread?

Tags: c++

If I, in one translation unit defines constants used to access into a `std::map`, and passes a lambda which uses these constants to an object accessed in another thread, can I then be sure the constants are initialized?

In the code below: an object of `class A` I instantiated in the main thread. In `A`'s constructor it registers a callback with an object. 
Say this object is accessed from another thread, defined in another translation unit, and calls the callback, will the value of `kInsertString` be correctly initialized at this time, or will I get a crash caused by trying to access the map using uninitialized variables? 
**EDIT:**

What if A constructor is interrupted by the other thread just after it registered the callback, so the lambda is called before constructor is finished?

```
const std::string kInsertString{"MyValue"};

class A {
 public:
   A(Object& obj) {
     obj.registerCallback([this](int n){ update(n); });
     ...
     ...
   }

 private:
   void update(int v) {
     values[kInsertString] = v;
   }

   std::map<std::string, int> values;
};

int main() {
    auto ptr = std::make_shared<A>(Object::getInstance());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can be sure that all global variables are constructed before `main` is called.

If this multithreading lambda thing happens in `main`, you can be sure global variables have been constructed by that point.

If this multithreading lambda thing happens in the constructor of a global variable, you can't easily be sure that the constructor where it happens runs after the constructor of `kInsertString`.

Comment: *"You can be sure that all global variables are constructed before main is called."* Not true, see [Deferred_dynamic_initialization](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initialization#Deferred_dynamic_initialization)

Comment: Yes, I was also thinking about that one.